# compact form for extended ratios?

Tags: notation, ratio

Is there a standard compact form for extended ratios, perhaps resembling the following?

$$
Q_{n=1}^5(z_n)=z_1:z_2:z_3:z_4:z_5
$$

Comment: What is an extended ratio?

Comment: A ratio between multiple integers, i.e. 2:3:4 as opposed to 2:3.

Comment: How is that even defined?